# html footer add it to end of line

Tags: html, css

I have footer as below and it shows properly with company name added to left of footer line.

```
<footer>
    <p>Company, Inc.</p>
</footer>
```

I want to add contact link at end of footer line which will be at end of line.

I tried this

```
<footer>
        <p>Company, Inc.</p>
        <p>phone number:123456789</p>
</footer>
```

But it gets stacked one below other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `footer { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }` to put them on the same line, separated by all of the free space in the footer.

```css
footer { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <p>Company, Inc.</p>
        <p>phone number:123456789</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: thnx do I need to add footer {....} in script? I added above in html but it actually displays `footer { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }` on page

Comment: @user2661518 either put it in `<style></style>` tags (ideally in the `<head></head>`), or put it in an external stylesheet with a `<link>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer>
    <p style="display:inline;">Company, Inc.</p>
    <p style="display:inline;">phone number:123456789</p>
</footer>
```